# Method which will be converted current date to next view

Tags: java

I need to create method which will be do next.
I need to enter in textview project name with username, curent date and time, it will be looks like this one, curent date is 7 15 2015, 9:58 AM:

- Project_User1_7_15_2015_9_57

---

If the curent date will be 9 18 2015 and time 7:15 PM, we will have next:

- Project_User1_9_18_2015_7_15

---

So we have "Project_User1" as static, and date & time shoud take current from PC and split it with "_"

Comment: Maybe use `SimpleDateFormatter`?

Comment: And just a little tip - put the date in year, month, day order, so that sorting the names alphabetically also puts them in date order (for each static prefix).

Comment: `new MessageFormat("Project{0,number,integer}_User{1,number,integer}_{2,date,d_mm_yyy_hh_MM}").format(new Object[]{project.getId(), user.getId(), new Date()})` ought to do it in one line. You can externalise the format and change it completely independently of the code too - `MessageFormat` is a very powerful and often overlooked tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat:

```
public String getName() {
    String text = "Project_User1_";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm");
    return text + df.format(new Date());
}
```

//Passing project and user strings

```
public String getName(String project, String user) {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm");

    return project + "_" + user + "_" + df.format(new Date());
}
```

//Reuse the Date Format rather than create a new one each method call

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm");

public String getName(String project, String user, DateFormat df) {
    return project + "_" + user + "_" + df.format(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Use. A. `MessageFormat`. Also, you probably want to explain that the OP wants to reuse the `Format` rather than create a new one each method call.

Comment: Thanks Boris. I have included that.